# Mysql Unknown System Variable

Tags: mysql

I am trying to increase the value of innodb_buffer_pool_size for my MySQL server. I added this line to the my.cnf file:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M
```

Before I added the line if I run `select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;` I get back 8388608. Now I am getting the error

```
Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'
```

Am I doing something wrong in my config file? or is that supposed to happen?

**Edit**
My server only has 512M of RAM, could this be somehow limiting the max size of the buffer pool?

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES - what does this show?

Comment: 241 rows come back, but innodb_buffer_pool_size isnt among them

Comment: Have you restarted mysql?

Comment: Also add this above that line  [mysqld] with the brackets included.

Comment: I restart mysqld each time i edit my.cnf. and [mysqld] is currently 3 lines above the messed up line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size
Command-Line Format --innodb_buffer_pool_size=#
Option-File Format  innodb_buffer_pool_size
System Variable Name    innodb_buffer_pool_size
Variable Scope  Global
Dynamic Variable    No
    Permitted Values
Type    numeric
Default 8388608
Min Value   1048576
```

only numeric values are allowed.
The default value is 8MB.

by http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size

Comment: i tried setting it to `innodb_buffer_pool_size=128000000` and it still fails.

Comment: Your link showed me the real problem. The max size is "80% of the machine physical memory size". I reduced the amount to 64M and was able to set it properly (though 128M is not even half of my installed memory).

Comment: odd, I received a -1 point, I think because I apparently downvoted the answer, but in fact I have never been to this question/answer before now!!! (and now I can't change it unless it is edited)